# Problem with CORS - Angular, problem with XMLHttpRequest

Tags: node.js, angular

i wanna call an API, form my backend (node) chrome console says this:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:4201/api//listar_clientes_filtrado_admin' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field content.type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

the problem it's form HttpErrorResponse who don't allow me consume the API.

this is the method i wanna use: (ClienteController)

```
const listar_clientes_filtrado_admin = async function (req, res) {
let registro = await Cliente.find();
res.status(200).send({ data: registro }); }
```

even i use this in my app.js (backend), but it's doesn't works.

```js
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Authorization, X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Request-Method');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    res.header('Allow', 'GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    next();
});
```

the others parts:

(Cliente.js)

```
    //GET
api.get('/listar_clientes_filtrado_admin',
    clienteController.listar_clientes_filtrado_admin
);
```

(Cliente.service.ts) - front angular

```
  listar_clientes_filtrado_admin(): Observable<any> {
let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content.Type', 'application/json');
return this._http.get(this.url + '/listar_clientes_filtrado_admin', {headers: headers});}
```

(component.ts)

```
ngOnInit(): void {
this._clienteService.listar_clientes_filtrado_admin().subscribe(
  response => {
    console.log(response);
  },
  error => {
    console.log(error);
  }
)
```

Comment: `Content.Type` is a typo. That should be `Content-Type`

Comment: god bless you my man <3 - that's was the error

Answer (score 0):

try to add middlewhere like this:

```
 var cors = require('cors')
 var app = express()

 app.use(cors())`
```

it's enable all cors request.

of course you need to run `npm i cors` before, to install it